# AngularJS variable scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, factory, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am sure I am missing some small detail. I have a factory which reads data from the server and retrieves JSON results. Then, in my controller I do the following:

```
.controller('homeController', ['$scope','RecentItems', function($scope,RecentItems)
{
  //scopes for the items 
  $scope.items={};
  RecentItems.getRecentItems().done(function(data){
    $scope.items = data;
    console.log($scope.items);
  });       
}])
```

In the HTML template i have an ng-repeat directive > `ng-repeat="item in items"`

And the results don't appear in the view. console.log($scope.items) displays the data in the console however, in the view the items appears to be empty.

I know that it has to do with the variable scopes in JavaScript rather than being an AngularJS problem

THIS IS THE JSON RESULT:

```
[
  {
    "iid": "32",
    "name": "Womens bag 2",
    "brand": "Gucci",
    "category": "Handtaschen",
    "minprice": "20",
    "retailprice": "400",
    "duedate": "2015-06-10 21:25:00",
    "description": "second bag",
    "img": "images/items/1433274066696.jpg",
    "current_price": "0"
  },
  {
    "iid": "31",
    "name": "Womens Bag",
    "brand": "Gucci",
    "category": "Handtaschen",
    "minprice": "20",
    "retailprice": "300",
    "duedate": "2015-06-10 21:25:00",
    "description": "Bag",
    "img": "images/items/1433274042147.jpg",
    "current_price": "0"
  },
  {
    "iid": "30",
    "name": "Watch2",
    "brand": "Swiss",
    "category": "Uhren",
    "minprice": "20",
    "retailprice": "200",
    "duedate": "2015-06-10 21:25:00",
    "description": "watch to test",
    "img": "images/items/1433273997525.png",
    "current_price": "0"
  },
  {
    "iid": "29",
    "name": "Watch",
    "brand": "Swiss",
    "category": "Uhren",
    "minprice": "10",
    "retailprice": "200",
    "duedate": "2015-06-10 21:25:00",
    "description": "Test",
    "img": "images/items/1433273879811.png",
    "current_price": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: What's inside `$scope.items`?

Comment: @softvar - inside $scope.items I get JSON response from the server as i have mentioned in the console i do get the right data

Comment: that's why I ask what exactly is that JSON object? Create a jsfiddle and I may help you better than.

Comment: Its not a working version because its just part of the code ..but you have the JSON response in the .js section so you can see it

http://jsfiddle.net/Kushtrim/jntwLLhf/

Comment: You may be iterating over the JSON object collection incorrectly when you use ng-repeat, that is why it may be helpful to see the object structure itself as @softvar has pointed out. You can copy/paste the JSON data, and append it to your question/ post. =)

Comment: Working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/jntwLLhf/1/

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi - I appended the JSON response in the question

Comment: @ShehryarAbbasi - the problem has to do with Javascript variable scope.. because when I debug the $scope.items outisde the function it gets empty ..

Comment: outside of what function?

Comment: Alll you need to do is add $scope.$apply();  The reason the fiddle works is because the results come back synchronously so they happen during the digest cycle.  Yours, I see .done(.. which suggests it is coming from the server asynch.  You just need to add $scope.$apply after you set the data.

Comment: add $scope.$apply();

Comment: @JimFallin ...yes I have read about digest cycle and it makes sense... I see it's kind of working now, I will have to just fix some details.